# How can I try out different things on my computer and restore it to its previous condition easily & gracefully?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, images

I’m starting to attend Hackathons and I'm in great need of a way to either *completely* restore my PC to a previous point in time, or deploy something that allows me to test out different things on my PC without really affecting it.

After every Hackathon, I used to spend a lot of time uninstalling/deleting waste programs manually (which I no longer need)—and it turns out many programs can’t be completely removed, even with Windows restore point tool or Windows image restore (eg. Visual Studio).

Some of my hacker friends have suggested either:

1. Creating and using a separate account—usually non-administrative—dedicated to my Hackathons and experimentations. I simply log in my hack account, mess it up as much as I want to, and eventually I can delete it. Supposedly changes applied in the Hack account affects nothing in the main account. Is that true?
2. Running some kind of virtual machine (would that satisfy my need?)

Advice/ideas as to which one to use? Any 3rd recommendation is also welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want maximum computing speed while at your competition then I'd say that it'd be worth it to create a ghost image of your system drive and put a fresh image on for the event. After, you can just restore your image and be back like nothing happened without worrying about any of it at the event.

If you want the absolute fastest VM then I'd have to give that to VMware. I don't usually endorse paid apps but it is much faster (in my personal experience) than anything else.

You also might want to use VMware to setup a little virtual network before the event so that you can test networking and cross platform apps quickly.

Meaning that you'll want to create another image for your events and just swap them out as needed. Keep a separate partition for your projects (and any other documents you may have) so that they don't get lost.